# SQLiteDatabse Delegate issue

Tags: swift

```
func executeQuery(query: NSString ) -> Int
{
    if  sqlite3_open(databasePath! as String, &database) != SQLITE_OK
    {
        println("Databse is not open")
        return 0
    }
    else
    {
        query.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("null", withString: "")
        var cStatement:COpaquePointer = nil
        var executeSql = query as NSString
        var lastId : Int?
        var sqlStatement = executeSql.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &cStatement, nil)
        var execute = sqlite3_step(cStatement)
        println("\(execute)")
        if execute == SQLITE_DONE
        {
            lastId = Int(sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database))
        }
        else
        {
            println("Error in Run Statement :- \(sqlite3_errmsg(database))")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(cStatement)
        return lastId!
    }
}
```

i have this function which return lastId as nil...anyone help me to solve this..
 is their "**sqlite3_stmt**" in swift?

Comment: It will be nil if it runs through the println

Comment: is their any mistake in my code? for firing the query?  because the condition is not match..

Comment: Basically it's ok. If the execute passed `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid` will hold the id of the last inserted id. Try adding more print statements to find the culprit